# Check to see if two dimensional array Index is empty, if it is not generate a new Index

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am basically creating a sort of ring toss application. I create a two dimensional array, "Game Board" as you will, populate the board with fifteen prizes in random locations each time the program is run. Then, I am to generate as if somone throws ten rings at the Index and mark where it lands and if it lands on a prize you get that prize if it doesn't you of course don't get any prizes.

Here I am having trouble generating all 15 prizes... I can print some prizes on the board but it never comes out quite at 15...

Here is the class that sets the prizes in random indexes "array" is my two dimensional array and prizes is an ArrayList that contains the prize list...

```
public static void setPrizes() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {

        row = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

        col = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

        prizes.add("puzzle");
        prizes.add("ball");
        prizes.add("cash");

        item = prizes.get(0 + (int) (Math.random() * 3));


        if(array[row][col].equals(" ")){
            array[row][col] = item;
        }else{
            inp = prizes.get(0 + (int) (Math.random() * 3));
            array[row][col] = item;
        }

    }

}
```

I can not understand why the if statement wont realize that a prize has already been placed there.

I Generated my board like this...

```
public static String[][] genBoard() {
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++) {
            array[row][col] = " ";
        }
    }
    return array;

}
```

The Board after the prizes have been generated...

```
public static void prizeBoard() {
    System.out.println("The Board");
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++) {
            System.out.print("[" + array[row][col] + "]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a few errors here:

Firstly you are using a double random and then rounding. Better is using a single `Random` object and the `nextInt` method.

Secondly, your for loop uses `<=` rather than `<` so it will be called 16 times rather than 15.

Thirdly, in each iteration you generate a location and then store an item there whether it already has one or not - both branches of your `if` statement assign `item` to the location. Whenever you generate an overlap you'll just overwrite the current item.

Fourthy, you are adding 3 new prizes in every iteration. Ideally that code would be in a constructor but, at the very least put it outside the loop.

Taking all these into account you would get:

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<String> prizes = Arrays.asList("puzzle", "ball", "cash");
int itemCount = 0;
while (itemCount < 15) {
    row = rand.nextInt(5);
    col = rand.nextInt(5);
    if (!array[row][col].equals(" ")) {
        array[row][col] = prizes.get(rand.nextInt(prizes.size()));
        itemCount++;
    }
}
```